# How to build single testNG e-mailable report from the different e-mailable html files

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

I have a scenario where I need to collect the data from different testng emailable-html report and make it as single one as look like same as testng-emailable report.

I didn't get any idea about this like how can I achieve it. I just want to create a seperate java project which will read the different html report and will make it final consolidate report as look like testng-emailable report.

Please give me some input on this, like Is there any listener can create the html template and accept the input data from html file.

I didn't look working code. Just looking some input to kick start this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG is open source software, so you could build your solution from the original code. You start with the [EmailableReporter](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/55d3ebd42be1d5eba7b6f374245a986c249c4291/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter.java) class. You collect the different results as XML files (testng-results.xml) and merge them in your code to get proper input for EmailableReporter. This will generate your desired output.